# column summary to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

My question is.
I have an UFO dataframe, where is 20 000 obs., I did summary of my data and get 51 states with numbers of observed UFOs. 
I was tried to do data.frame from that like:

ufo_by_state <- data.frame(observations = summary(ufo_clean$`Event State`)

But the problem is, that not flexible for further manipulation. 
I need to do dataframe with colnames = c("states", "observations") and rownames = Alabama,Alaska,Arizona...etc. 
I will need to cbind with population, and build some histograms. 
I was try many things, which i know at this moment, but still no result.

Thank you!

Comment: You can create the 'data.frame' like `v1 <- summary(ufo_clean$EventState); df1 <- data.frame(states = names(v1), observations = v1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `summary` on a single column output a named `vector`.  So, creating a data.frame with two columns would be to extract the 'names' and the `values` or the `key/value` pairs as separate column in a `data.frame` call

```
v1 <- summary(ufo_clean$EventState)
df1 <- data.frame(states = names(v1), observations = v1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```